# php - different return value for isset() via cli

Tags: php, command-line-interface, isset

Create a `PHP` file with this content:

```
<?php
function something( $value )
{
     echo "something: ".isset( $value['i'] )."\n";
}

$value1 = "I'm a string";
$value2 = array( "aString" => "I'm also a string, but inside an array");

something( $value1 );
something( $value2 );
?>
```

Save the file, open your browser, point to your site where the file is. You will get something like this:

```
something: something:
```

Fire up your desired console program, and run:

```
<prompt> php -f <path/to/file.php>
```

And you will get:

```
something: 1
something:
```

**Why?** I'm not talking about the difference in the newlines as the browser is rendering `HTML` and I didn't put `<pre>` tags. Instead, I see a difference in the logic of how `isset()` is returning `FALSE` and via command-line is returning 1 for the case where you check for an index in a string.

The question came to my mind because is the same code that differs its output between command-line and HTTP request.

Comment: I got `something:
something:` from my CLI. PHP 5.4.7

Comment: `i` is referring to a key that is not set just to test what the question is for. @alex I'm not high and I re-issue the command `php -f deleteme.php` and I got what the question said. `PHP 5.3.24`

Comment: @alex, I open a Centos VM and also my results are as described in the question with `PHP 5.3.3`

Comment: @alex, from [DOCS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php): `5.4.0 Checking non-numeric offsets of strings now returns FALSE.`